# Как использовать Express js? Вывод базы данных mysql в HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars

Пишу сайт. Делаю всё по информации в интернете и урокам. У меня один файл со скриптом на Node.js, собрал все зависимости через Browserify. Конечный файл подключил к HTML странице, открыл её, но консоль выдала ошибку в файле bundle.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:29561)
    at Object.145../utils (bundle.js:30663)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.141../application (bundle.js:28801)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.139../lib/express (bundle.js:28129)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

Оказалось, дело в Express. Если его убрать, ошибок в bundle.js нет. Как я понял, он не используется на стороне клиента, и служит только для создания локального сервера разработчика?

Когда открываю сам скрипт на localhast:8080 всё работает идеально, но мне нужен сайт.

Как мне переделать следующий код, чтобы он везде нормально работал?

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 5,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  database: "users",
  password: "password"
});

app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.listen(8080);

  function vyvod_bd(){     
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
      pool.query("select @i:=@i+1 num, user, city from users, (select @i:=0) x order by user;", function(err, data) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        res.render("main.hbs", {
            users: data
        });
      });
  });
}
```

Бонус вопрос: нельзя каким-то подобным методом вывести базу данных в файл HTML, а не в шаблон? А то получается, что я открываю HTML, а потом скрипт загружает такой же шаблон, только с информацией с базы данных. Может для этого нужен jQuery?

Код с шаблона:

```
<tr><th>Num</th><th>user</th><th>city</th></tr>

                {{#each user}}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{this.num}}</td>
                        <td>{{this.user}}</td>
                        <td>{{this.city}}</td>
                    </tr> 

                {{/each}}
```

Comment: где не работает то?

Comment: @PaulWall  Когда я открываю файл html, скрипт не работает

Comment: для чего вам функция `vyvod_bd` которая нигде не вызывается? а вы в эту функцию засунули свой роут, который не отрабатывает.